# My program does not print out the full array

Tags: arrays, c, output

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEW_LINE 10
#define TAB 9
#define SPACE 32

int main() {
    int c;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int word[10][10] = { { 0 } };

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != TAB && c != NEW_LINE && c != SPACE) {
            word[counter1][counter2] = c;
            ++counter2;
        } else {
            counter2 = 0;
            ++counter1;
        }
    }

    for (int a = 0; a <= 9; ++a) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int b = 0; b <= 9; ++b) {
            printf("%4d", word[a][b]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to get the user input and save the words that appear. My idea was I would first get the letters and save them to an array making a word, and then save each word into the array (forming 2D array). The problem is I only get the first character array printed out and the rest is ignored for some reason. I am a beginner at C programming so dont be mad if there are some stupid mistakes.

**Here is the output:**

```
Hello World

  87 111 114 108 100   0   0   0
```

[image: Image of the same output]

Comment: `87 111 114 108 100 0` corresponds to `"World"`

Comment: Your program works **as is** on https://ideone.com/uxgNtU

Comment: Are you on Windows? If you are, your `ENTER`s may be received as 2 characters inside your program: `10` and `13`. Try adding `#define CARRIAGE_RETURN 13` and include it in the `if`. The usual effect of `CARRIAGE_RETURN` on output is to reset the print position to the beginning of the line.

Comment: BTW: the canonical way to write your loops is `for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a)`. Your loop is good, but it *feels wrong* to see `<=` in there.

Comment: @pmg: the CR LF sequences are transparently converted to single newlines by the Microsoft runtime by default.  Ths behavior can be disabled but it is quite unlikely the case on the OP's system.

Comment: As an aside: (1) you lack any index checks -- too many words or too many characters in a word (especially the last one) can cause crashes. (2) It would be good to have at least one additional character in each word which stays zero so that you have proper C strings (so that you can use `printf("%s")`), (3) Name your variables better, e.g. `word_index` and `char_index`. Put the indices for the input in a scope (enclose the input code with `{...}`). (4) Even better, use nested `for` loops also for input. (5) Use scanf `%s` with a maximum field width, "word splitting" is its exact use case.

Comment: In your original question, you had `word[0][counter2] = c;`, which would explain why you didn't see the characters from the word "Hello", but then you changed the code in the question to `word[counter1][counter2] = c;`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems OK as long as you do not input more than 10 separators and none of the words are longer than 10 characters.  I am getting the full output on my laptop, only a final newline should be output for good style.

The snapshot posted is incomplete: the first line corresponds to the second word `World` but it should have 2 more zeroes at the end and the top pixels of another line can be seen at the bottom of the image. Try and enlarge the size of your VS Debug output panel.

To avoid undefined behavior, you should protect your program against buffer overflows, for example by ignoring characters that fall outside the 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEW_LINE 10
#define TAB 9
#define SPACE 32

int main() {
    int c;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int word[10][10] = { { 0 } };

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != TAB && c != NEW_LINE && c != SPACE) {
            if (counter1 < 10 && counter2 < 10) {
                word[counter1][counter2] = c;
                ++counter2;
            }
        } else {
            counter2 = 0;
            ++counter1;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            printf("%4d", word[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I dont know why the last 2 zeros are not showing, for some reason the number of zeros varies depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue of the program not printing out the full array, we need to ensure that the program is not writing outside the boundaries of the array. One way to do this is to dynamically allocate memory for the array based on the number of words and the length of each word.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).